# MEAN stack - having trouble displaying data in table

Tags: angular, express, mean

I'm trying to create a MEAN web app. Currently, i'm attempting to create a table which shows a list of users in my database, however currently with the following code I only receive table headers with no data. Could anyone please help me identify what may be causing the issue?

user-list.component.html:

```
<div class="example-container"class="mat-elevation-z2">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> id </th>
      <td mat-cell contenteditable="true" *matCellDef="let users"> {{ users.id }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let users"> {{ users.email }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="password">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Password </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let users"> {{ users.password }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

user-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

import { User } from "./user.model";
import { UsersService } from "./user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'user-list.component',
  styleUrls: ['user-list.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'user-list.component.html',  })

export class UserListReport implements OnInit {
  users: any = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'email', 'password'];


  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
    this.usersService.getUsers();
    this.usersService.getUserUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 0);
    })    
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { User } from "./user.model";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class UsersService {
  private users: User[] = [];
  private usersUpdated = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getUsers() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; users: any }>("http://3.135.49.44:8080/api/user")
      .pipe(
        map(userData => {
          return userData.users.map(user => {
            return {
              email: user.email,
              password: user.password,
              id: user._id
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedUsers => {
        this.users = transformedUsers;
        this.usersUpdated.next([...this.users]);
      });
  }
  getUserUpdateListener() {
    return this.usersUpdated.asObservable();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you subscribe the subject(`usersUpdated`) too late, you can change the function execution order to get the correct data.

```js
@Component({
  ...

export class UserListReport implements OnInit {
  ...


  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
    // this.usersService.getUsers();
    this.usersService.getUserUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 0);
    })  
    // trigger getUser function after getUserUpdateListener has been subscribed
    this.usersService.getUsers();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks although still doesn’t seem to have sorted the problem. I still receive not data in the data table

Comment: I create a [online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ibn4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) for you. You can compare what different than your code

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create the example. I still can't seem to get the data to pull through to the table though. our user-list.component.html and user-list.component.ts code is exactly the same, so i guess it must be the service code?

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure the data get from the API(http://3.135.49.44:8080/api/user) is correct data structure. maybe that have some error.

Comment: When I use that url direct in the browser, it lists all the users, therefore the error must be in transferring the data to the form. Any ideas? Again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, I think your data structure is the key point of your problem, you can create fake data(`usersService's getUser function`) in my example to debug it